# Correct way to do log4j2 remote logging via a Socket after version 2.8?

Tags: log4j2

I have a number of processes running on separate EC2s and I want to send all the logs to a centralized server running in our office.  (I'm using the Routing appender to write them to separate logs)  What is the currently accepted way to send logs via a Socket appender and receive them using the TcpSocketServer?

Currently, I'm using the TcpSocketServer from the 2.8.2 release and I'm using 2.13 on the EC2s; the EC2 clients are configured as follows

```
<Socket name="socket" host="IP.GOES.HERE" port="7777" connectTimeoutMillis="3000" reconnectionDelayMillis="3000">
    <SerializedLayout />
</Socket>
```

It works, but I have several concerns:

1. When I restart the TcpSocketServer the client doesn't reconnect.
2. When the client is having trouble connecting to the server it blocks the client.  Do I need to have an Async appender wrapped around the Socket?
3. Is there a security hole?  Why was the TcpSocketServer removed but the Socket appender remains?

Answer (score 0):

The TcpSocketServer was meant to be a sample application. I would not recommend using it in production as is. It also introduces a security risk if you do not prevent arbitrary connections and/or use the SerializedLayout. Json would be a much better choice.

The SocketAppender will reconnect. The best way to use it is by configuring it with a DNS name for the host where the host returns multiple IP addresses. The socket appender will reconnect to any of them if the connection drops.

You might want to look at [Logging in the Cloud](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html) for other suggestions.